# Should I use SSL to secure CMS backend?

Tags: ssl, content-management-system

Would it be beneficial to use SSL on a CMS backend? The only sensitive data I can think of is the password. The password, as it is now, is encrypted with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and a key.

Any comments are appreciated :)

Comment: You should store passwords hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: Thanks. I will see what I can find at security.stackexchange.com . Will probably end up buying a certificate then :)

Comment: [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) handles message (sender-to-receiver) encryption. I would look at http://security.stackexchange.com/ and see what you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you absolutely should. While you use a good encryption, unless you're adding a SALT to the password, it is likely easily looked up in a pre-computed hash table (rainbow table) and you can probably find it online within a matter of seconds.

CMS is something you definitely want to be secure about since it potentially gives someone complete access to the content of your website to maliciously alter as they wish, or possibly exploit from there to gain access to the server or disable your login.

Https doesn't really add any overhead, but it's very simple to add. I'd recommend it, even though it's not going to provide perfect security, some is better than none!